# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php

Very simple issue we cannot resolve. The following code does not redirect properly:

```
$location = str_replace("http","https",$this->page->current_url);
header( "Location: ".$location );
```

I get a 400 Error: "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please."

How can I redirect in PHP from a page served over HTTPS to a page served over HTTP for scenarios such as secure login and then redirect to nonsecure app page?

Comment: Basic debugging first. What does `$location` contain after you do the replacement?

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Without having much experience on this topic, maybe adding port helped here. Meaning; `https://host/path` --> `http://host:80/path`. Given the information you provided it sounds like browser is not switching to http port but continues to communicate with https port.

Comment: @Harism Thats what I was thinking, but yea, output the $location string to see what's going on

Comment: Pekka - Duh - I have no clue why I did not look at $location. It contained http//localhost:443/[...] which is invalid. I simply remove the :443 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

try this, for me works fine

```
<?php
if  ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
    {
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $good_url = "http://" . $host . $request_uri;

            header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header( "Location: $good_url" );
            exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for http to https and https to http (use some tweaks to check)

First check whether the https is ON on your hosting if yes than redirect the URL to https using below mentioned function in PHP

```
function httpToHttps() 
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
    {


    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    } 
    else 
    {

    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_UR

I"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
    header( "Location:foo.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can cause such a problem, but you should add an **exit** after calling the header function. This makes sure that the following code will not be executed and the HTTPS request itself returns no data. The header function should be called before anything is returned.

```
$target = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('Location: '.$target, true, 303);
exit;
```

Comment: Something like this might do the trick. My uneducated guess would be problem lies within [http-keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Persistent_connections). Which in this case is causing browser to use existing https connection while it should open a new one to http port.

Answer (score 0):

Duh - I have no clue why I did not look at $location. It contained http//localhost:443/[...] which is invalid. I simply remove the :443 and it works fine.

Comment: @Mat: There doesn't appear to be another answer that matches this one.